# python 2d list remove targets

Tags: python

```
vals = [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
targets = [2]

def remove_vals(vals,targets):
    lst = []
    for lst_ in vals:
        for x in lst_:
            if x not in targets:
                lst.append(x)  
    return lst
```

Output: `[3,3,4]`
Output I need: `[],[3],[3,4]`

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension will be simpler here. In this case, you'll need a nested list comprehension to preserve the input list nested structure:

```
[[i for i in l if i not in targets] for l in vals]
# [[], [3], [3, 4]]
```

If you want to use a regular for loop, you could do something like:

```
lst = []
for lst_ in vals:
    new_l = []
    for x in lst_:
        if x not in targets:
            new_l.append(x)  
    lst.append(new_l)
```